# WP/WC missing argument in WooCommerce Function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I have Wordpress with WooCommerce installed and I am trying to use this code to login an admin user:

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user = get_userdatabylogin( $username ); // get_user_by('login', $user_login);
    $id = $user->ID;

    wp_set_current_user( $id, $user->user_login );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $id );
    do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
}
```

But it is returning this error message:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for wc_maybe_store_user_agent() in
>   plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php
>   on line 1516

I have tried looking around online but no one seems to have had this issue.

Comment: Is the issue resolved or you still facing the problem? If it is resolved you should post an answer here.

Comment: do not use get_userdatabylogin function as it deprecated by WP. Use get_user_by() instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {

    //determine WordPress user account to impersonate
    $user_login = 'guest';

    //get user ID
    $user = get_userdatabylogin($user_login); // below WP 3.3.0

    //$user =  get_user_by('login', $user_login); above or equals WP 3.3.0

    $user_id = $user->ID;

    //login
    wp_set_current_user($user_id, $user_login);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
    do_action('wp_login', $user_login);
}
```

There is a hook in WooCommerce like this.

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'wc_maybe_store_user_agent', 10, 2 );
```

The "**wc_maybe_store_user_agent**" expects 2 parameter. If the user ID is not set, it will show the error you mentioned.
Test my snippet above

Function is at line 1516 in plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php

```
function wc_maybe_store_user_agent( $user_login, $user ) {
    if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_allow_tracking', 'no' ) && user_can( $user, 'manage_woocommerce' ) ) {
        $admin_user_agents   = array_filter( (array) get_option( 'woocommerce_tracker_ua', array() ) );
        $admin_user_agents[] = wc_get_user_agent();
        update_option( 'woocommerce_tracker_ua', array_unique( $admin_user_agents ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'wc_maybe_store_user_agent', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Yeah thanks you. You 're totally right, 2 arguments - one missing

Comment: Good one . . . .

Answer (score 7):

You missed one parameter. Try this.

```
do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login, $user );
```

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login/

Comment: it doesn't seem to be logging in

Comment: do you have any ideas what could be stopping it from logging in?

Comment: @charlie, what function or how is the whole code being constructed? how are you calling these?

Comment: exactly what was missing in my case!